# Windows Media Encoder : How to set average bitrate in audio Bitrate-based mode

Tags: audio, average, encoder, bitrate, windows-media-encoder

How to set average bitrate in audio Bitrate-based mode?
In Window media encoder SDK, it tell that I must specify average bitrate.
Is it using the same `audience.SetAudioConfig(0, 2, 44100, 192000, 16);` to set the bitrate as CBR?

Answer (score 0):

I just know that Bitrate-based VBR, encoder must start(encoder.Start();) twice. Now, I can record the sound.